# Dynamically Create Query String for Django > MySQL from JSON

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, django-queryset

I am new to Django and am having some issues writing to a MySQL dB. What I am trying to do is loop through nested JSON data, and dynamically create a string to be used with a save() method.

I've looped through my nested JSON data and successfully created a string that contains the data I want to save in a single row to the MySQL table "mysqltable":

```
q = "station_id='thisid',stall_id='thisstaull',source='source',target='test'"
```

I then try to save this to the table in MySQL:

```
    b = mysqltable(q)
    b.save()
```

But I am getting the error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'mysqltable'

What I think is happening is that it doesn't like the fact I have created a string to use in b = mysqltable(**q**). When I just write out the statement like the below it works fine:

```
    q = mysqltable(station_id='thisid',stall_id='thisstaull',source='source',target='test')
    q.save()
```

But I am not sure how to take that string and make it available to use with b.save(). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why did you convert your JSON data to a string? It would be much more useful to keep it as a dict, then you could pass it direct to the model initialisation with `mysqltable(**data)`. That string format is useless as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to handle the nesting in the JSON and that I knew the statement before the .save() was mysqltable(variable1='value1",variable2='value2'). So, it was simple to create that string by looping through the key:value pairs dynamically to create key:value pairs only for elements that existed in the JSON. I don't want to write null values to the dB for elements that do not exist in the JSON. Is there an answer you can point me to for flattening the nested JSON for a simple insert into the table?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are looking for. As I and steel have both said, you can pass the dict with the current attributes directly. Since you're obviously already looping through the nested dict to create a string for each item, you can just pass the current sub-dict instead. If you're still having problems, you need to post the full processing code and an example of the nested JSON.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel and steel! I finally got this working using a dictionary rather than creating the string. I handled the nesting by appending one dictionary to another (both created from the original json.loads()). I then used "del" to delete the duplicate nested JSON element from the new dictionary. I used ".pop()" to change the name of some of JSON keys that were different from the dB fields. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead string, create a dictionary, and then pass it directly to mysqltable:

```
mysqltable(**dictWithData)
```

Of course you can re-parse string onto dictionary, but this is useless work...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've responded on the main thread looking for a good example of what you are suggesting for flattening nested JSON.

Comment: How you construct a string? Something like `st += "%s='%s';" % (jsonKey, jsonValue)`. Instead this use `dictWithData[jsonKey]=jsonValue`. This will add key/value pairs into dictionary, not into string.